N8n startup after connecting to new database with existing n8n tables attempts Migrations
I am moving a 1.51.2 n8n installation to a cloud sql database and gcp cloud run. I’ve successfully exported and imported the existing postgres data to the new could sql instance. I sucessfully deployed the Docker with n8n 1.51.2 and it connects to the new cloud sql database but I get these errors at startup:
Error: There was an error running database migrations
QueryFailedError: relation “migrations” already exists
I don’t understand why it’s trying to create a migrations table when it already exists. What is the logic and when migrations are attempted?
Thanks
I was expecting a normal startup and for migration not to be attempted
